# Best way of doing global polling in react app

Tags: reactjs

So i have few polling services that are triggered when user is authenticated and are running all the time under hood on Navigator level so code looks like this

```
const Navigator() => {
   usePolling1();
   usePolling2();
   usePolling3();

   return <AppComponent/>
}
```

Each of these polling are updating the state where we use `recoil` for state management. Issues that i'm facing are:

1. Dom tree gets re-render
2. If i render component that is reading from the state that have been updated from the global polling it doesn't get unmounted even if i'm not on this route anymore, so how to handle `global polling` what is the best practice but when i leave the component to get unsubscribed from state and not being rednered anymore